# Angular - map converts nested array from the initial object into empty array

Tags: angular, dictionary

I have an object stored in localStorage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('employeeDepartmentCost', JSON.stringify(this.departments));
```

I want to recover this object and convert it to a custom class that looks like this:
[image]

This is how I try:

```
 this.departments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employeeDepartmentCost')).map((department: any) => {
          var newDep = new Department(department.name,
            department.rows.map(row => new EmployeeCostRow(row.name, row.employees, row.salary)
            ));
          return newDep;
```

or

```
this.departments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employeeDepartmentCost')).map(department =>
        new Department(department.name,
          department.rows.map(row => new EmployeeCostRow(row.name, row.employees, row.salary)
          )
        ));
```

The problem is that the object is not converted correctly, the rows array becomes an empty array after applying map.
[image]

How should I solve this in order to wait for the values?
Or how can I store a custom class in local Storage so I wouldn't need to use map anymore.
Thanks!

Comment: if you fixed your problem, plz share your solution. if my answer helped you, I would appreciate if you accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from these lines

```js
if (useTemplate === 0 && -1) {
   this.rows = [];
}
```

`useTemplate` is 0 as it is absent from your `new Department`, and `-1` is the same as `true`, so rows is reinitialized to empty array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
this.departments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employeeDepartmentCost'))
.map(department =>new Department(
   department.name, 
   department.rows.map(row => ({name: row.name, employees: row.employees, salary:row.salary} as EmployeeCostRow)  )
));
```